# Java - Implementing DAO

Tags: java, sqlite, dao

I'm struggling to implement this DOA class. I've added the `getConnection` and `closeConnection` methods, however, when adding the `ArrayList<Employees>` I always get an error. I've added my code below. I've been given a UML diagram to use.

What am I doing wrong? Could someone possibly point me in the right direction?

[image: Class Diagram]

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class EmployeeDAO {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException {
        Connection con = null;
        Statement st = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;

        Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");

        try {
            String dbURL = "jdbc:sqlite:employeeDatabase.sqlite";
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL);
            st = con.createStatement();
            rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM employees;");

            while (rs.next()) {
                System.out.println(rs.getString("ID"));
                System.out.println(rs.getString("Name"));
                System.out.println(rs.getString("Gender"));
                System.out.println(rs.getString("DOB"));
                System.out.println(rs.getString("Address"));
                System.out.println(rs.getString("Postcode"));
                System.out.println(rs.getString("NIN"));
                System.out.println(rs.getString("JobTitle"));
                System.out.println(rs.getString("StartDate"));
                System.out.println(rs.getString("Salary"));
                System.out.println(rs.getString("Email"));
            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (rs != null) {
                    rs.close();
                }
                if (st != null) {
                    st.close();
                }
                if (con != null) {
                    con.close();
                }
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation
>   problems:
>   Employees cannot be resolved to a type
>   Illegal modifier for parameter selectallEmployees; only final is permitted
>   Employees cannot be resolved to a type at EmployeeDAO.main(EmployeeDAO.java:61)

Comment: Is there a reason you are doing this yourself rather than using a framework like Hibernate or MyBatis?

Comment: What is the error that you get?

Comment: I don't see `getConnection` or `closeConnection` defined in your class.

Comment: I don't see any ArrayList either.

Comment: Your main method should preferably sit entirely outside of your model.

Comment: @AngerClown Assingment. I can't do anything apart from what they've stated.

Comment: @Thilo Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
 Employees cannot be resolved to a type
 Illegal modifier for parameter selectallEmployees; only final is permitted
 Employees cannot be resolved to a type

 at EmployeeDAO.main(EmployeeDAO.java:61)

Comment: @cricket_007 Do you mean  public static void main(String[] args)? If I don't have it, I get an error in the console stating it needs to have that line of code.

Comment: @4castle Sorry, I thought everything from public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException { and below was the getConnection and closeConnection method. My bad.

Comment: You do need that method, but not within `EmployeeDAO`... Make a completely separate Java class solely for the purpose of a main method. That sits "outside of" your database model. Like your `Controller` class's main method

Comment: @cricket_007 Yes, it's in my controller class. Would I have to extend my Controller class to my EmployeeDAO in order for it to not give me that error?

Comment: Forget it... My personal preference for how you should organize your code won't fix the error. Seeing as you have no `selectallEmployees` method (as what you error says), then we can not help you solve it

Comment: Your error indicates that you need to recompile all of your files, because one of them has a compiler error, and is making your code crash at runtime. The code you posted does not match the error you're getting.

Comment: It's not clear that you understand what those diagrams mean, but you have to define methods for each method named in each box in the diagram, i.e. inside your EmployeeDAO class you must write `public ArrayList<Employee> selectAllEmployees() {...}`.

Comment: @4castle May I show you something within a chat? If possible. Thank you.

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou Ah! Thank you my friend.

Comment: @AngerClown lmfao that name is hilarious

Comment: The code you pasted is not the one that gives you error. Never do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the triangles are protected or public fields. The red boxes are private fields. Green circles are all public methods. The C on the top circle is a constructor.

Your question's code follows none of that...

According to your diagram, your class needs to be written starting like so.

```
public class EmployeeDAO {

    private Connection con;
    private Statement st;
    private ResultSet rs;

    public EmployeeDAO() { 
        // TODO: Should initialize 'con', probably
    }

    public Statement getConnection() { 
        return st; // confused... getConnection should 'return con', no?
    }

    public void closeConnection() { 
        if (con != null) con.close();
    }

    public ArrayList<Employee> selectAllEmployees() {
        return new ArrayList<Employee>(); // TODO: replace with database stuff
    }

    // etc...
```

And your main method should not be in that class at all.

```
public class Controller {

    public Controller() { }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EmployeeDAO dao = new EmployeeDAO();
        List<Employee> emps = dao.selectAllEmployees();

        for (Employee e : emps) { 
            // etc...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I've added the following code to getConnection()Connection connection = null;
  try {
   Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
   connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:employeeDatabase.sqlite");
  } catch ( Exception e ) {
   System.err.println( e.getClass().getName() + ": " + e.getMessage() );
   System.exit(0);
  }
  System.out.println("Connection - database driver found");